# '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime' - used strptime as well

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to select the data frame using my train period shown below but it ran into error always.

```
train_period = [
['1/1/2018', '10/30/2018']]

train_period = [[datetime.strptime(y,'%m/%d/%Y') for y in x] for x in train_period]

for tp in train_period:
        print()
        #print('Begin:%d End:%d' % (tp[0], tp[1]))
        print()
        df_train_period = df_sku[
                (df_sku['To_Date'] >= tp[begin]) & (df_sku['To_Date'] <= tp[end])]
```

Comment: What does `df_sku['To_Date'].dtype` show? You may need to convert it to `np.datetime`

Comment: it's a date column which has 1/1/208, 1/15/2018/, 2/1/208, 2/15/2018....

Comment: Well then you need to convert: `df_sku['To_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sku, format='%m/%d/%Y')` and then try your code

Comment: no worries, I didn't downvote but you need to post your raw data or sample data, code to recreate your df, the desired output and your current code and errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `'To_Date'` column needs to be of `dtype` `np.datetime` in order to do datetime string filtering, so firstly convert first:

```
df_sku['To_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sku, format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

then your code will work. You can always check the `dtype` by calling `df_sku['To_Date'].dtype`